# Why does my Android app show all of the activities?

Tags: java, android

So, I made an app and now instead of just showing one thumbnail or app, it shows all of my activities! Even though, I uploaded the signed and packaged app, this is happening on other people's phones too! What should I do?

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UDhAjMtNSqj-UHdiCZBM8X08RLIrOgDAavKQ1posyo0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each activity with a launcher category will be listed in the application launcher:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```